# Transistor amplifier circuits

Tags: transistors, resistors, amplifier, parallel

[image]

What is the ac collector resistance for the transistor Q1? I am having trouble finding which resistors are in parallel with each other in the circuit above. I want to find the voltage gain and power gain for the circuit in terms of beta,i.e beta parameter of transistor

Comment: Please crop the picture to a scale where it is readable.

Comment: I don't see any parallel resistors. Not sure what parallel resistors have to do with finding the collector resistance.

Comment: Can you provide more background? Are you a student, and is this an assignment? If you are a student, what class are you taking? I suspect that what you want to know is the impedance "looking in" to the collector of Q1, right? I think you are doing AC analysis of this circuit. Please comment.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry folks for disturbing you i found out the answer myself what i needed to do was just make the ac equivalent circuit for the given circuit and further proceed with problem . For ac equivalent the capacitor behaves as a short so resistors such as R3 becomes parallel with Rc and so on.......

Comment: That's what I thought you were doing. Good job, and thanks for following up.